# A linear algebra proof involving induction

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

1. Let $V$ be an $n$ -dimensional vector space and let $W \subseteq V$ be an $m$ -dimensional subspace. For each $\mathbf{v} \in V$, define $S_{\mathbf{v}}=\{\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}: \mathbf{w} \in W\}$, and let $U=\left\{S_{\mathbf{v}}: \mathbf{v} \in V\right\}$. Define addition in $U$ so that for any $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in V$
   $$
   S_{\mathbf{x}}+S_{\mathbf{y}}=S_{\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}}
   $$
   and define scalar multiplication so that for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$
   $$
   k S_{\mathbf{x}}=S_{k \mathbf{x}}
   $$
   It can be shown that $U$ is vector space (you do not need to prove this).

Given the above information, I need to:

Prove, by induction, that for any $k \geq 1$ and any choice of $c_{1}, \ldots, c_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{x}_{1}, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_{k} \in V$, if $\mathbf{v}=\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_{i} \mathbf{x}_{i}$ then
$$
S_{\mathbf{v}}=\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_{i} S_{\mathbf{x}_{i}}
$$

This is what I have done:

For $i=1, v=c_{1} x_{1}$.

Then, $S_{v}=\left\{v=c_{1} x_{1}+w: w \in W\right\}$

That is,

$S_{v}=c_{1}\left\{x_{1}+w / c_{1}: w \in W\right\}$, since $c_{1}$ is invertible,

$=c_{1}\left\{x_{1}+w^{\prime}: w^{\prime} \in W\right\}$

Hence the assumption is true for $\mathrm{i}=1$.

Let us assume the result for $\mathrm{k}-1$.

That is,

$S_{v}=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} c_{i} S_{x_{i}}$ where $v=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} c_{i} x_{i} .$

Whenever $v=\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_{i} x_{i}$, then by initial step of induction,

$\begin{aligned} S_{v} &=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} c_{i} S_{x i}+c_{k} S_{x_{k}} \\ &=\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_{i} S_{x i} \end{aligned}$

Hence the proof follows by induction.

Would this be correct?

Answer (score 1):

When $k=1$ It Is contained in the informazioni given, it's the closure for scalar product. Then if you use the case $k=1$, inductive hypotesis and the sum in $U$, you conclude

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.